# How to store different single array to database?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two arrays which I can get after form submit:

```
$product_id = $request->get('product_id');
// [1, 3, 4]
$quantity = $request->get('quantity');
// [5, 1, 2]
```

Now I want to submit this arrays into database where I want to pick the `purchase_price` from product database. I'm not sure how to assign `product_id` to product_quantity (index 0 to 0, 1 to 1, 2 to 2) and store into database.

Sample data to store into carts:

```
[1  5  120 ],
[3  1  230 ],
[4  2  340 ],

foreach ($product_id as $product) 
{

}

DB::table('carts')->insert(
  ['product_id' => '', 
    'quantity' => 0,
    'purchase_price' => 
   ]
 );
```

Just for clarification:
`product_id` and `quantity` come from dynamic input box means number of `product_id` and `quantity` are same but it could be n times as user wanted. So I store it as arrays.

Now from this array I wanted to store it in database where I want to store with `product_id` with `quantity`.

Comment: I am not clear can you please give more details

Comment: product_id and quantity comes from dynamic input box means number of product_id and quantity are same but it could be n times as user wanted. So I store it as arrays

Comment: Now from this array I wanted to store it in database where I want to store with product_id with quantity .

Comment: Please EDIT your question and include the extra details there. Do not clog the question with comments on your own question.

Comment: You have to insert data or update?

Comment: Insert only I need to add

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
foreach ($product_id as $key=>$product)
{
    //select purchase price from table by using the $product value
    $purchase_price = *your select code here*
    DB::table('carts')->insert([
        'product_id' => $product,
        'quantity' => $quantity[$key],
        'purchase_price' => $purchase_price
    ]);
}
```

Let me know if not works

Answer (score 0):

Lets give you some suggetions:

If you have below array - if not then make it array like below:

```
$dataset = [
    0 => [
        'product_id' => 1, 
        'quantity' => 5,
        'purchase_price' => 120,
    ],
    1 => [
        'product_id' => 3, 
        'quantity' => 1,
        'purchase_price' => 230,
    ],
    2 => [
        'product_id' => 4, 
        'quantity' => 2,
        'purchase_price' => 340,
    ]
];
```

Now you have to write INSERT query for this:

```
$result = Cart::insert($dataSet);

if ($result)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

You will get an idea how to do it after seeing above code...good luck

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this sample.
you can parse 2d array and convert it to json to store in the database then decode back:

```
        $product_id = [1,2,3];
        // [1, 3, 4]
        $quantity = [5,1,2];
        // [5, 1, 2]
        $output=[120,230,340];
        $out=[];
        for ($i=0; $i < count($product_id); $i++) {
            $out[$i]=[$product_id[$i],$quantity[$i],$output[$i]];
        }
        dd(json_encode($out));
```

output:

> "[[1,5,120],[2,1,230],[3,2,340]]"